# Starting Size for an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I want to use an ArrayList (or some other collection) like how I would use a standard array.

Specifically, I want it to start with an intial size (say, SIZE), and be able to set elements explicitly right off the bat,

e.g.

```
array[4] = "stuff";
```

could be written

```
array.set(4, "stuff");
```

However, the following code throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>(SIZE);
array.set(4, "stuff"); //wah wahhh
```

I know there are a couple of ways to do this, but I was wondering if there was one that people like, or perhaps a better collection to use.  Currently, I'm using code like the following:

```
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>(SIZE);

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
   array.add(null);
}

array.set(4, "stuff"); //hooray...
```

The only reason I even ask is because I am doing this in a loop that could potentially run a bunch of times (tens of thousands). Given that the ArrayList resizing behavior is "not specified," I'd rather it not waste any time resizing itself, or memory on extra, unused spots in the Array that backs it.  This may be a moot point, though, since I will be filling the array (almost always every cell in the array) entirely with calls to array.set(), and will *never* exceed the capacity?

I'd rather just use a normal array, but my specs are requiring me to use a Collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial capacity means how big the array is. It does not mean there are elements there. So size != capacity.

In fact, you *can* use an array, and then use `Arrays.asList(array)` to get a collection.

Comment: Understood, re: capacity.  As far as using Arrays.asList(), thought about it... but then I (well, the library) have to iterate over the the entire array at the end, each time.  I suppose this is no worse than iterating SIZE times to add all the nulls?

Comment: don't worry so much about linear complexity.

Comment: You could be right. I almost didn't bother posting this, as it's a fairly picayune topic.  My implementation works fine, it just seems... wrong.

Comment: You can use @Bozho's suggestion to create a List full of nulls of any size with Arrays.asList(new Object[SIZE])

Comment: ^^ I like this one, as it does essentially the same thing, and looks less... unseemly. =]

Comment: Marked this as correct for combination of "don't worry so much about linear complexity" and Peter's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I recomend a HashMap

```
HashMap hash = new HasMap();
hash.put(4,"Hi");
```

Comment: Which nearly guarantees that I have a bunch of wasted spaces in the array, no?

Comment: yes, you waste more memory, but you don't have to waste time sorting all again like arraylist do.

Comment: Further, HashMaps aren't Collections.

Comment: Not with a (Hash)Map: every put() on a map creates only one entry for that particular key/value pair. The important point is that the '4' is indeed a key, and not an index anymore. So if you executed `map.put(4, ...); map.put(-1000, ...); map.put(999, ...)` the map would contain only three values, and e.g. `map.size()` would return 3.

Comment: Sorting is an absolute non-issue, in my use case.

Comment: @Lars: But Maps are backed by arrays that are sparse by design.  Granted, I'm only "wasting" 4 bytes/empty spot in the array, but this could easily balloon when we potentially have tens to hundreds of thousands of these.  Further I have to worry about the HashMap resizing itself, collisions, and all that other fun stuff.  With an array (or arraylist) that I *know* will always have *exactly* SIZE elements, this seems like waste.

Comment: @biggusjimmus your argument isnt valid. Look at the implementation of an ArrayList. Every time you exceed the size of the array list, it doubles itself in size and copies itself over a new array. Your still "wasting" space especially when you have many elements.

Comment: @user: how is my argument invalid if I *never* exceed the capacity provided in the constructor?

Comment: ... I *am* using the entire array (or at least almost the entire array).  Every time. Also, I'm wasting *much* less space than I would be with a hash map. Thanks for shouting though.

Comment: Without microoptimization, from a purely API point of view, this is a very good answer. +1

Comment: @biggusjimmus: Yes and no. _Hash_ Maps use an array to hold the anchors for the hash bucket lists, and increase this array in size as it fills up with valid anchors (starting size in my JDK is 16). So yes, in the (improbable) worst case, adding 1000 entries to the HashMap could end up with an anchor array of 1024 entries; but in the (equally improbable) best case the anchor array would never have to be grown at all. Tree Maps otoh have completely different characteristics.

Comment: It does occur to me that if I were to use a HashMap, I could set the initialCapacity to SIZE, and the loadFactor to 1.0, and then I could essentially be use it just like a normal array, and since I'm using integers for my keys, I don't think I would have to worry about collisions (Integer.hashCode() == Integer, right?). Still, since I have to convert it to a collection anyway, a hashmap doesn't really work for me.

Comment: @user: OK, but that doesn't make it a Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your main point is memory. Then you could manually do what the Java arraylist do, but it doesn't allow you to resize as much you want. So you can do the following:

```
1) Create a vector.
2) If the vector is full, create a vector with the old vector size + as much you want.
3) Copy all items from the old vector to your new vector.

This way, you will not waste memory.
```

Or you can implement a List (not vector) struct. I think Java already has one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hashmap would be a great ideia.
Other way, you could just start the array with a big capacity for you purpose.